# Asking many questions related to the same problem

Tags: discussion

I've just come across [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105214/i-need-help-converting-bat-files-to-sh-files) in my reviewing, where someone is requesting one-for-one translation of `.bat` files to `.sh`. and have noticed in the comments the following statement:

> You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

While for the question itself I actually agree with this, lets assume the person then follows this advice. They go ahead, and start attempting to translate it themselves. Lets also assume they are failing miserably.

Is it acceptable to be asking (up to) 5 or more questions based on the same basic question (or request rather), on how to translate a specific piece of code, "because I don't know how to do it"?

Sure, they may provide relevant examples of their attempts which in turn makes the question valid and perfectly reasonable, but would we not be better off allowing them to address these major issues within the one question? In bulk? As in, an entire portion of code?

To compare to the linked question, their asking for 4 complete files, I'm talking more about complete statements, a few lines, etc.

**Edit:**

Infact, [Ken White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62576/ken-white) made a comment on the same question that addresses this discussion perfectly:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a coding language translation service. We're glad to help when you've made an effort yourself and run into difficulties; you can then explain the problem you've encountered, post the relevant portions of the code, and ask a specific question. But you have to make that effort first. If you can't start at all, hire a contractor to do it for you. Good luck.

Comment: I realised that but thought I would ask in order to start a discussion. Changed my mind anyway and asked the original author directly.

Comment: Nevermind, just checked your discussion.

Comment: I think he means that the OP isn't shown the reasons that people are voting for closure until the post is actually closed. But that's a good thing. He doesn't seem to comprehend that people might disagree with him, which is why he has a non-binding vote in the first place. The message is then clearly displayed when consensus is reached. (Ish)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Exactly right!

Answer (score 4):

> Is it acceptable to be asking (up to) 5 or more questions based on the same basic question (or request rather), on how to translate a specific piece of code, "because I don't know how to do it"?

If each of those questions are individually good questions, yes, absolutely.  If those questions have other problems (which seems likely in that situation, but it *is* possible that they're good) then those problems can be addressed in each question.

> would we not be better off allowing them to address these major issues within the one question? In bulk? As in, an entire portion of code?

It might be better for *that one person* to just ask us to do their entire project for them, instead of them having to do it themselves, sure.  Nobody else is going to benefit from such a question though.  Various specific questions about problems that arise over the course of attempting to solve that problem have a reasonable chance of actually being problems other people have with their own solutions, and given that the question would be describing that problem, rather than just dumping some code and asking for it to be translated, those other people with a similar problem would actually have a shot at finding said question.  Thus (assuming those other, more specific questions, are actually good questions that meet the site's guidelines) those questions would actually be helpful, and add value to the site, unlike the current question.

Comment: Sounds good. I guess the question would be much more of a "question" if they attempted to do it themselves and then put in effort.